# Find the probability that the largest number shown by any throw is r

Tags: probability

So I have a pretty hard dice question on a past exam that has thrown me a bit:

A dice is rolled a random number $n$ of times. Let $A_i$ be the event that $n=i$ and suppose that $P(A_i)=1/2^i$

a.) How would i find the probability that the largest number shown is $r$?

b.) How to find the probability that $n=2$, given that the sum of the scores is $5$ and the first throw showed $2$.

So for part a.) I have that $P(A_1)=1/2$, $P(A_2)=1/4$, $P(A_3)=1/8$, $P(A_4)=1/16$ $P(A_5)=1/32$, $P(A_6)=1/64$

Is this correct or have I made a huge error? I cannot find any similar style questions about throwing a die a random number $n$ times and am thus struggling to work out how i would solve a question like this.

Many thanks for your help

Comment: im not sure it is that simple i think i have to do a bit more working out than that.   
part b just says "find the probability that n=2, given that the sum of the scores is 5 and the first throw showed 2."

Comment: Never mind! Part (b) asks for the *conditional* probability of $A_2$ given some other event; the *unconditional* probability of $A_2$ is $1/4$.

Comment: so how would i find out the conditional probability? would i use one of the conditonal probability identities? I think i understand part b more than part a.)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An outline of a solution of the first problem has been given by Ross Millikan.  We consider the second problem.

Let $T$ be the event $n=2$. Let $S$ be the event the sum was $5$ and the first throw was $2$. We want $\Pr(T|S)$. We have
$$\Pr(T|S)=\frac{\Pr(T\cap S)}{\Pr(S)}.$$
Now we want to calculate the two probabilities on the right.

For $\Pr(T\cap S)$, note that for this to happen, we must have $n=2$ (probability $\frac{1}{4}$). **Given** that $n=2$, the probability that the first toss is $2$ and the sum is $5$ is $\frac{1}{6^2}$. Thus $\Pr(T\cap S)=\frac{1}{144}$.

Next we find $\Pr(S)$. The event $S$ can happen in several ways, with (i) $n=2$; (ii) $n=3$; (iii) $n=4$.

We have already calculated the probability of (i). For (ii), we must have $3$ tosses (probability $\frac{1}{8}$), then a $2$ (probability $\frac{1}{6}$), then $1$ and $2$ or $2$ and $1$ (probability $\frac{2}{36}$), for a total of $\frac{1}{8}\cdot \frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{2}{36}$.

For (iii), we must have $4$ tosses, and the pattern $2,1,1,1$. The probability is $\frac{1}{16}\cdot \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^4$.

To calculate $\Pr(S)$, add together the probabilities (i), (ii), (iii). Now you have all the ingredients for calculating $\Pr(T|S)$.

Comment: Thankk you! So i have $P(S)=(1/6^2*1/4)+(1/8*1/6*2/36)+(1/16*(1/6)^4)$ then just put this into the formula to get t given s? Thanks so much for your help

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, that's what one does. The conditional probability will be quite large, since (ii) and (iii) make a much smaller contribution than (i).

Comment: So just checking that i.) = $(1/6^2*1/4)$. Sorry just to confirm as you mentioned we had already worked i.) out. Many thanks

Comment: Yes, I had written $\frac{1}{144}$, which is the same thing.

Comment: yes that is what i noticed, sorry, i mean is $(i)=P(A \cap b)$?

Comment: its okay i have just realised it is!!

Comment: In the answer, I called it $\Pr(T\cap S)$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  Can you figure out the chance that all $n$ throws are $1$?  That is the chance that $1$ is the largest number.  Then can you figure out the chance that all the throws are $1$ or $2$?  That is the chance the largest number is no larger than $2$, so if you subtract the chance that it is $1$ you have the chance that the largest number is $2$.  Continue.

Added:  the chance you get all $1$'s is $(\frac 16)^n$.  The chance you get all $1$'s and $2$'s is $(\frac 26)^n$, so the chance the highest is a $2$ is $\frac {2^n-1^n}{6^n}$  Similarly, the chance the highest is $k$ is $\frac {k^n-(k-1)^n}{6^n}$

Comment: that is what i have done so far but i am stuck and dont know where to go with it..

Comment: That should give you the answer to a for each $r$, counting up from the bottom.  I don't understand the question in b.  $n$ was the number of throws.  Are you saying the total of $n-1$ throws (after the first) is $3$ and finding the chance that you got a $3$ instead of $1,1,1$ or $2,1$ or $1,2$?

Comment: part b just says "find the probability that $n=2$, given that the sum of the scores is 5 and the first throw showed 2." In regards to a.) i think i have done all of my working out wrong. i got that as n/6 but i just worked out how to find the probability that each number is rolled. I dont know how to work this out properly i am a bit confused. Could you help me get it started?

Comment: I wonder how that changes if we are interested in second largest...

Answer (score 0):

One approach for (a) would be to calculate the cumulative distribution function for the largest number observed (call it $F_L(r)$) and we can get the probability mass function (call it$f_L(r)$) by noting:

$$f_L(r)=F_L(r)-F_L(r-1)$$

Say we roll the dice $n$ times, then the probability that the largest observed value is less than or equal to $r$ is: $\mathbb{Pr}[R \le r]=\left(\frac{r}{6}\right)^n$, where $R$ is the result of one roll.  Each roll is independent and identically distributed so that is why the result is the probability of one roll being $\le r$ to the $n^{th}$ power.  Finally, we want to sum up the probability that all rolls are $\le r$ and that we rolled $1,2,3,...$ times total.  So we have:

$$F_L(r) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{Pr}[R \le r]^n\frac{1}{2^n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{r}{12}\right)^n=\frac{1}{1-\frac{r}{12}}-1=\frac{r}{12-r}$$

Now do the subtraction to get $f_L(r) \ ,r=1,2,3,4,5,6$.

**Note:** For sanity's sake, the pmf sums to 1 per [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28r/%2812-r%29-%28r-1%29/%2813-r%29,r,1,6%29)

Comment: Thank you for this, although im not sure it was intended to be worked out this way. So is answer to part a just $1$? If so i cannot understand how this can be.. Thanks for your help

Comment: so far i have that  I have that $P(A_1)=1/2$, $P(A_2)=1/4$, $P(A_3)=1/8$, $P(A_4)=1/16$ $P(A_5)=1/32$, $P(A_6)=1/64$ and $P(largest number thrown \le 1)=1/6$, $P(largest number thrown \le 2)=1/3$, $P(largest number thrown \le 3)=1/2$ ect, is there anyway of using this in my solution? Many thanks

Comment: I'm not sure why you are focusing on the $P(A_i)$ values so much.  This is just taking the formulas given to you and substituting values for $i$.  They come into play in my formula as conditional probabilities, in other words, the summation I have is saying, take the probability that $1$ roll is at most $r$ **given** you only throw once and multiply by the probability you only throw once.  Add to this the probability the first and second rolls are at most $r$ **given** you only throw twice times the probability you only throw twice...and so on.

Comment: Note: $F_L(r) = f_L(1)+ ... + f_L(r-1) + f_L(r)$ so that $F_L(r) - F_L(r-1) = f_L(r)$ as stated.  The answer is definitely not $1$.  That part was to verify that my formula for $f_L(r)$ satisfied: $\sum_{r=1}^{6}f_L(r)=1$ which is a requirement for all probability mass functions.

Comment: Thank you very much, i have the answer as $$\frac{r}{12-r}$$

Comment: The answer to (a) is $\frac{r}{12-r}-\frac{r-1}{12-(r-1)}=\frac{12}{(12-r)(13-r)}$